# how to require a module without mentioning the relative file path

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

this is an example folder structure

```
folder1
--lib
----app.js

folder 2
--www
----Application.js
```

The Application.js file in the folder2 requires app.js file from the folder1 in the following way `var app = require('../../folder1/lib/app')`
and then Application.js is browserified.

What I want to achive is require the app.js into the Application.js without mentioning the path .ie `var app = require('app')` and without changing the folder structure, but on being browseried it will map the actual file i.e. folder1/lib/app.js for require('app').

EDIT

I am thinking about creating a file in folder1 that will be responsible to browserify the code in folder2.
Ex: $folder2> node ../folder1/build.js www/Application.js
will output a browserified file mapping require('app') to the app.js in folder1

Comment: You've tagged your question with [tag:requirejs]. How are you actually using RequireJS? (How do you load it, configure it, etc.)

Comment: I am building the script with browserify ex:borwserify Application.js > path/to/some/folder and the requirejs contains the actual paths

Comment: I've removed the [tag:requirejs] from your question since you don't seem to be using it. Please note that RequireJS is a [*specific product*](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html). The tag is for questions that pertain to that product.

Comment: but, my question is both about requirejs and browserify, what i am looking for is auto aliasing the path in requirejs before the file is browserified.

Comment: Well, then we're back to square one. Please edit your question to indicate how you load and configure RequireJS. The closer your question gets to a [mcve] the more likely you are going to get an answer that actually solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use [`app-module-path`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path) for this.

My folder structure:

```
index.js
app/
   lib/
     hash.js
   controllers/
     index.js
   middleware/
     auth.js
```

and in `index.js`:

```
require('app-module-path').addPath(__dirname);
```

Then for example in `controllers/index.js`, I can just do this:

```
var auth = require('app/middleware/auth');
var hash = require('app/lib/hash');
```

This is for nodejs. Now for browserify you can use [`aliasify`](https://github.com/benbria/aliasify).

```
replacements: {
  "app/(\\w+)": "app/$1"
}
```

It makes things much cleaner.